# Not able to randomly search the item from the array

Tags: java

I have no idea why I only can search the item in the array by ascending order only. If I randomly search from the array it will show me this line:

```java
System.out.println("Data not found");
```

Code:

```java
for(int i = 0; i < staffCount; i++) {
   if(username.equals(staff[i].GetStaffID()) && pass.equals(staff[i].GetPassword())){
       if(staff[i].GetUserRole().equals(Staff.userRole.USER) && staff[i].GetStatus().equals(Staff.status.ACTIVE)){
           int select2 = 0;
           boolean userCheck = false;
           String categoryID;

           do{
               System.out.println("\nWelcome, " + staff[i].GetStaffName());
               System.out.println("1. Apply Claim");
               System.out.println("2. Edit Claim Record");
               System.out.println("3. Cancel Claim Record");
               System.out.println("4. Logout");
               System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
               select2 = input.nextInt();

                //APPLY CLAIM
               if(select2 == 1){

                   String catId, applyPosition;
                   float amount;

                   System.out.println();
                   System.out.println("Apply Claim Screen");
                   System.out.println();

                   System.out.println("Available Claim Category" + claimCount);
                   for(int j = 0; j < claimCount; j++){
                       System.out.println("(" + (j+1) + ")" + " Category");
                       System.out.println("Category ID : " + claimCategory[j].GetClaimCategoryID());
                       System.out.println("Category Name : " + claimCategory[j].GetClaimCategoryName());
                       System.out.println("Applicable position: " + claimCategory[j].GetApplicableToPosition());
                       System.out.println("Limit: " + claimCategory[j].GetLimit());
                       System.out.println();
                   }

                   boolean checkCat;
                   boolean checkClaim = false;
                   for(int j = 0; j <= claimCount; j++){
                       do{
                           System.out.print("Please enter category ID: ");
                           catId = input.next();
                           if(catId.equals(claimCategory[j].GetClaimCategoryID())){
                               checkCat = true;
                           }else{
                               System.out.println("Data not found");
                               checkCat = false;
                           }
                       }while(!checkCat);

                       if(staff[i].GetPosition().equals(claimCategory[j].GetApplicableToPosition())){
                           System.out.print("Enter claim amount: ");
                           amount = input.nextFloat();
                           do{
                               if(amount <= claimCategory[j].GetLimit()){
                                   System.out.println("Amount claimed.");
                                   System.out.println();
                                   checkClaim = true;
                               }
                               else{
                                   System.out.println("Please do not exceed the limit.");
                               }
                           }while(!checkClaim);

                       }else{
                           System.out.println("You position are not eligible to apply.");
                       }
                   }

               }
               //END OF APPLY CLAIM

               else if(select2 < 0 || select2 > 4){
                   System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
               }

           }while(select2 != 4);
       }
   }
}
```

[image: output of the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to invert the order of the for and the do:

```
do{
    checkCat = false;
    for(int j = 0; j <= claimCount; j++){
        System.out.print("Please enter category ID: ");
        catId = input.next();
        if(catId.equals(claimCategory[j].GetClaimCategoryID())){
            checkCat = true;
            break;
        }
    } // end for
    if(!checkCat)
            System.out.println("Data not found");
}while(!checkCat);
```